# How do I render big objects without performance issue

Tags: opengl

I have 2 objects that are rendered every frame, one of them renders fast and is updated every frame and the other renders slow (big object that uses instanced rendering). Since I can't use opengl in two different threads, every time the big object is updated (for that, I'm calling glBufferData and resetting its buffer with new data), the program lags and the light object stops rendering. I imagine one solution is to render parts of the heavy object every frame, instead of all of it at once. But this division is not very practical to do, so is there a better way?

Comment: "Since I can't use opengl in two different threads"  Oh?  Why not?

Comment: Everywhere I see people saying it's bad :P Also, is it even possible to have 2 opengl contexts actived at the same time?

Comment: It would help to add a much more concrete example of what you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't included code nor a descriptive detail, I'll try my best to make sense of it. If your large model is static, and unchanging, your best bet is to create a VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) and assign the data once, then render using the provided handle, read more here; https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples

However, from your outline, I believe your large model has modified vertices every frame. Furthermore, I believe you're saying that your use `glBufferData` every frame to update the vertex/index data on the GPU side.

The more efficient way to do this is would be to instead map the index/vertex buffer and modify only what needs to be changed, as opposed to resetting the data every frame.

**C++**

To do this, you map the buffer and get a CPU-side write only buffer;

```
void* result = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY)
```

You can then write over the values which need to be changed. After doing this, simply release the pointer to have it update;

```
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

The `void*` can be cast to your vertex data structure and then modified as if it were an array of vertex data. For example;

```
m_Buffer = (VertexData*)result;
```

Also, please note that `glMapBuffer` will wait for until the GPU has finished using the buffer. If you don't want a synchronous write, then use `glMapBufferRange`;

```
void* result = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, getSize(), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT)
```

The following are specifications, explanations and tutorials of this method. It would be beneficial to read them and fully understand what is happening.

glMapBuffer: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml

glMapBufferRange: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml

Buffer Mapping: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping

Buffer Streaming: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming